# How to insert button into Grid from ViewModel C# class in windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I can insert button to a grid control from the code behind file as

```
var fElem = new Button();                 

fElem.Content = "button text";
bgGrid.Children.Add(fElem); // bgGrid defined in xaml
```

How can I add the same button to the grid from the view model class?

Comment: Of course, it is possible but it is not recommended. Your ViewModel should not be manipulating your View. It defeats the whole point of MVVM.

Comment: But intention is to insert user control based on data loaded in Viewmodel. Any pointers to achieve this will be helpful.

Comment: I still think your question needs to be a little clearer then. What does the data in your ViewModel look like? Is it a List? Do you want to have 1 button for each item in that List?

Comment: I would bind the visibility of the button to a property of the ViewModel.

Comment: @ChrisLeyva Requirement is inserting button to page grid control from its Viewmodel class. Lets assume number buttons ie equal to the count of the List.

Comment: @FabianH. Visibility cannot be applied since there are no defined buttons is xaml.

Comment: @NOOB Do you wish to add the Button to the layout Grid control on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code-behind of the xaml page (xaml.cs) you need to publicly expose the grid

```
public Grid MyGrid => bgGrid;
```

Then you can get access to it from your ViewModel like so:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
var page = rootFrame.Content as YourPageClassName;
var fElem = new Button();                 
fElem.Content = "button text";
page.MyGrid.Children.Add(fElem);
```

However, this is not MVVM at all.

Comment: bgGrid element is inaccessible. How can i make it public? Presently defined using x:Name

Comment: var bgGrid = page.Content as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid; 
this worked for me.

Comment: Sure, that works because the grid, in your case, is the root of your page content.